# Custom splitting operation

Tags: c#, string, text, xpath, split

Think of I have several XPath expressions like:

```
loan:_applicant/base:_entity/person:_locations/base:SmartRefOfLocationeJDvviUx[base:_entity/contact:_category/base:_underlyingValue='Personal' and base:_entity/contact:_confirmedByResident/common:_isConfirmed/base:_underlyingValue='true' and base:_entity/base:_process/base:_entity/base:_id/base:_underlyingValue = /loan:Application/base:_process/base:_entity/base:_id/base:_underlyingValue]/base:_entity/base:_id/base:_underlyingValue
```

I try to split these expressions using `/base:_entity` parts as a splitter like this:

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "/base:_entity" };
string[] pathTokens = xPath.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

But I need to prevent splitting when `/base:_entity` is between `[` and  `]` chars.

I have to produce the following string array as output for the sample expression that I wrote above is:

```
"loan:_applicant"
"/person:_locations/base:SmartRefOfLocationeJDvviUx
[base:_entity/contact:_category/base:_underlyingValue='Personal' and base:_entity/contact:_confirmedByResident/common:_isConfirmed/base:_underlyingValue='true' and base:_entity/base:_process/base:_entity/base:_id/base:_underlyingValue =  /loan:Application/base:_process/base:_entity/base:_id/base:_underlyingValue]"
"/base:_id/base:_underlyingValue"
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use some cute Regex like `(?<=^.*\][^\[]*|^[^\[\]]*)/base:_entity` and then Regex's method Split. It uses positive look-behind to check whether the first bracket on the left is the closing bracket ']' or there is no bracket at all.